# Strange toilet pause

Tags: toilet

Lately, our Toto toilet flushes weakly and makes a bubbly sound—unless we hold the lever down a bit (longer than before) to be sure it flushes completely and normally. Then, the tank refills, stops for a few seconds when it is almost full, and then refills again for about a second or two before it stops completely. Any idea what is happening? Have I got a problem?

Comment: Seems like two problems:  1) drain clogged or vent issue; 2) refill stopper set a tad too high.

Comment: Does the water in the bowl rise higher than it used to?

Comment: No, if anything, the water in the bowl is lower or about the same.

Comment: Based on above comments, I'd guess it's a blockage in the vent pipe....